# Add routing to OpenShift 3

Tags: node.js, dns, routes, openshift

I've got an on NodeJS application running on OpenShift 3 (Starter) and previously on OpenShift 2 I could add a DNS / routing to access my NodeJS application not only from the eary long URL from OpenShift but also from my own domain.

Now with OpenShift 3 (Starter) I cannot find any option to add my own routing to it and even when I add the CNAME to my domain to the eary long URL from OpenShift it suddenly says that the application isn't available.

Does any one of you have a clue of what I'm missing and/or doing wrong?

Comment: The only way to have a custom domain name in Online Starter, is to use CloudFlare or similar as a proxy in front, with CloudFlare accepting the requests for the custom domain and then forwarding them to the hostname that OpenShift Starter gives you for your application.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CloudFlare. Do I need to make a CNAME for this or what do you propose?

Comment: If you are not familiar with CloudFlare, go to there site and read about their services. https://www.cloudflare.com/

Answer (score 0):

Custom routes are not available in OpenShift Online Starter. You can see the differences between Starter and Pro on the [pricing page](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html#online-plan-comparison).